# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')" when I use a component from my personal library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, rollupjs

I created a personal library (UI library / style guide) to standardize the components of my application.

Everything was working perfectly until I use a component that uses useState hook.

For some reason, every time I try to use a component with useState, the following error appears in my application:
[image]

My library uses:  React, sass, storybook, typescript and rollup.

And my frontend application uses: Next, axios, yup, formik and typescript.

My library files settings:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@lucasReghini/library",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/lucasReghini"
  },
  "version": "0.0.11",
  "description": "react ui library",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "rollup": "rollup -c",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "author": "Lucas Reghini Magalhães",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.10",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^22.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^2.1.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.4",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "rollup": "^2.78.1",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^4.2.2",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.54.5",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "@types/react": ">=18",
    "react": ">=18",
    "react-dom": ">=18"
  },
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@types/react": ">=18",
    "react": ">=18",
    "react-dom": ">=18"
  }
}
```

rollup.config.js

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      postcss(),
      image()
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.(css|less|scss)$/],
  },
];
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Default
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    // Added
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "rootDir": "src"
  }
}
```

Folder structure
[image]

And the component that return the error when its used in the main FE application:

```
import React, { ChangeEventHandler, useState } from 'react';
import './Input.scss'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import { inputTypes } from '../../enums/presets';
import { eyesClosed, eyesOpen } from '../../icons'

//improving note
//settup package to accept import type from other files
export interface InputProps {
    id?: string,
    label?: string,
    error?:boolean,
    message?: string,
    disabled?: boolean,
    autoComplete?: boolean,
    isPassword?: boolean,
    types: inputTypes,
    onChange?: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>
}


const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({id, disabled, label, message, error, onChange, autoComplete, isPassword, types, ...props}) => {
    const [isView, setIsView] = useState(false)
    
    const classNameInput = classNames({
        form__input : true,
        'error': error,
        'font-16': true,
    });

    const type = isPassword ? isView ? 'text' : 'password'  : types 

    return (
        <div className='form'>
            <input onChange={onChange} className={classNameInput} type={type} id={id || 'ipt'} autoComplete={autoComplete ?'' : 'off'}  placeholder=" "/>
            <label className='form__label' >{label}</label>
            {isPassword && <img className='icon' src={isView ? eyesClosed : eyesOpen} onClick={() => setIsView(e => !e)}/>}
            {error && <span className='message'>{message}</span>}
        </div>
    )
} 

export default Input
```

Component structure:
[image]

I believed it could be the component, so I created other components using useState and following the same structure, and when used in the frontend they return the same error. That is, the problem is not with the component itself, but with any component that uses useState.

This is the (simple) usage in the main application:

```
import { Button, Input } from '@lucasReghini/library';

      <Input
        autoComplete
        id="email"
        label="Email"
        message="teste"
        onChange={() => {}}
        types="email"
      />
```

obs: The button component (that do not use useState) works normally when I use it, its just the Input or other component with the useState.

Just to make sure, this is the main application package.json

```
{
  "name": "main-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@lucasReghini/library": "^0.0.11",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^12.2.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^2.0.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "next-images": "^1.8.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.7.13",
    "@types/react": "18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5",
    "sass": "^1.54.5",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}
```

Im using npm@6.14.15 yarn@1.22.19 and node v16.14.0

I've tried several things, like removing and adding react-dom from peerDeps, removing everything from dependencies, changing "external" inside rollup.config.js etc.
None of this seemed to work, and when I run the rollup command, no errors are returned and it works normally.

Has anyone gone through this error? Maybe it's something to do with the library being react and the main-frontend being next?

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me with the same problem: [Creating react library with rollup.js i get error null (reading 'useState')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71848226/creating-react-library-with-rollup-js-i-get-error-null-reading-usestate)

TLDR: add `external: ["react", "react-dom"]` to your rollup.config.js