# Rollup component "Invalid hook call" after being built, and imported in another React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup, rollupjs

I'm having some weird issues here with Rollup. If anyone is more-versed than I am, please, any help would be appreciated!

First off, I need to say that I see some similar issues here:

- [Creating react library with rollup.js i get error null (reading 'useState')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71848226/creating-react-library-with-rollup-js-i-get-error-null-reading-usestate/72604051#72604051)
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14721

However even after trying these above proposed fixes, I am still having the same issues and I cannot put my finger on the exact problem as to what im missing. I hope that one of you can point me in the right direction.

I also decided to create a public github repo for this over here for my full project:

"Library"
https://github.com/FredM7/test-button

"Application"
https://github.com/FredM7/simple_site

I'm trying to keep things very simple. Right now I don't even try to import CSS yet, I just want React to work with Rollup as I would expect.

Let me explain my summarized issue here:

- When I take the above project, and I build it locally on my machine, it builds successfully. I see a `/dist` folder bing created

[image]

All of this, appears correct to me so far. I'm happy.

- Now, I also need to mention that I am installing this on my OTHER project this way, inside my `package.json` file:

```
"@myorg/test-button": "file:/Users/fred/Documents/Development/test/test-button/dist",
```

You can see for now, I use `file:/` so that I can develop locally instead of deploying to NPMJS which takes too much time. By the way, after depolying this to NPMJS, I get the same results, no difference. (I read somewhere about react symlinks, npm link or something, but I doubt this is the issue? Anyways.)

- In another React project, I would use it like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactPaymentButton } from "@myorg/test-button";

export const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="pt-4">
      <ReactPaymentButton label="Hello" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If my payment button does NOT use a `useEffect`, the Button gets imported fine in my OTHER project as indicated here, we see "Hello" which is the button.

[image]

- However the moment I add the useEffect on the `test-button` project/repository (as indicated by my GitHub repository above) i get the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

At this point im not sure what im missing, does anyone else perhaps know what i could be missing?

Any help woudl be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide that would help! Any comments welcome! Thanks

EDIT:
I also executed `npm ls react` in my simple `website` as indicated here:

[image]

```
typescript@1.0.0 /Users/fred/Documents/Development/test/simple_site
├─┬ @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.7
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ html-react-parser@4.2.10
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-markdown@8.0.7
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-redux@8.1.3
│ ├── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └─┬ use-sync-external-store@1.2.0
│   └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.22.0
│ ├─┬ react-router@6.22.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0
```

I don't specifically see my package here.

EDIT:
I also performed the linking as suggested by ALTHAF PJALEEL below.

In my `Library`
[image]

In my `Application`
[image]

Usage in `Application`
[image]

New `npm ls react` output

```
simple-site@1.0.0 /Users/fred/Documents/Development/test/simple_site
├─┬ @myorg/test-button@0.0.1 extraneous -> ./../test-button
│ ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0 extraneous
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 extraneous
├─┬ @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.7
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ html-react-parser@4.2.10
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-markdown@8.0.7
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-redux@8.1.3
│ ├── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └─┬ use-sync-external-store@1.2.0
│   └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.22.0
│ ├─┬ react-router@6.22.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0
```

I see a new `react@18.2.0 extraneous` there

EDIT: I added my "Application" project above.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the very same issue while developing a component library and here is what helped me fix it. In my case, I was facing the issue when I use the local copy of the Library, not when I push to npm. So I suggest you to please re-check that part.

**If you are facing this locally only, then**

As the error message indicates, you are having duplicate react copies here. One from the project which exports the test-button component (lets call it Library) and the other from the project which imports the test-button component (lets call it Application).

To fix this issue, you need to tell your Library to use the same copy of react which your Application uses. `npm link` is the easiest way to do this. Pleas remove the file protocol for installing the Library and follow below steps

1. Inside your Library, do `npm link`
2. Inside your Library do `npm link ${path_to_Application}/node_modules/react`
3. Inside your Application, do `npm link ${name of your Library ('name' field from package.json)}`

This should fix your issue. Here is the [official doc](https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#:%7E:text=This%20problem%20can%20also%20come%20up) on this. (open this in Chrome)

**if you are also facing this after pushing your Library to npm as well, then**

Few suggestions I can give which you can check are

1. Do `npm ls react` inside Application to see the react copies being used
2. If there are multiple copies, your Library and Project might be asking for incompatible versions of `react`. Bring them to the same version

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Yes I have read something about this. However I'm not sure if this is the issue - why would I get the same error after I have deployed it to `npmjs`? I dont want to do this for the package that i install from npmjs as well...

Comment: You can try this once to see if this is the issue. However if you are very sure it happened after pushing to npm as well, then In that case you will need to check if the version of react specified in both the projects fall into the same semver or not. You can do `npm ls react` inside the Application to see the react copies it uses

Comment: I have updated my question to include the output for `npm ls react`

Comment: Also have added the linking output I have performed to the question.

Comment: Can you also push your Application to github ?

Comment: Sure! I have edited my question - I have added my "Application" github link as well for you to see here:
https://github.com/FredM7/simple_site

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with the same suggestion that I gave. See the result here https://i.imgur.com/iDYjHKa.png. 
I had to make some other changes inorder to setup the project, but once I reached your issue, I was able to fix it by linking Application's react copy inside Library.
You can try uninstalling react from your Library and then following my suggestion